# BibLaTeX - addbibresource not working

Tags: biblatex, bibtex, overleaf, external-files

I am using a self-hosted instance of Overleaf/ShareLaTeX, and I cannot get BibLaTeX to work. My preamble looks like this:

```latex
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{subfiles,fancyhdr,amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage[style=ieee,refsegment=chapter]{biblatex}
\usepackage[breaklinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[hang,flushmargin]{footmisc}
\usepackage{myMacros} % A quick package that I made to hold some macros

\addbibresource{references.bib}
```

I am using the Overleaf default compiller, `pdfLaTeX`. I know that Overleaf provides automatic support for BibLaTeX, as I have seen articles about using it on their website (for example, [this one](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/how-to/Using_bibliographies_on_Overleaf)).

**The problem, I think, is that `\addbibresource{references.bib}` is not doing anything at all.** I tried changing it to things like `\addbibresource{referencesloremipsum.bib}` and `\addbibresource{references.asdfbib}`, and I did not get any error messages saying that those files did not exist.

I have spent a while trying this with and without Biber installed (via `tlmgr install biber`), etc, and nothing works. I believe that using the `BibTeX` fallback *may* have worked (I am not sure), but I don't want to do that.

In case it helps, I am using `subfiles`.

Here are the compilation logs. As you can see, there is no mention of `references.bib` at all:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.23 (TeX Live 2021) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2021.7.2)  25 JUN 2022 01:39
entering extended mode
 restricted \write18 enabled.
 %&-line parsing enabled.
**main.tex
(./main.tex
LaTeX2e <2021-06-01> patch level 1
L3 programming layer <2021-06-18> (/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex
/base/report.cls
Document Class: report 2021/02/12 v1.4n Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo
File: size10.clo 2021/02/12 v1.4n Standard LaTeX file (size option)
)
\c@part=\count182
\c@chapter=\count183
\c@section=\count184
\c@subsection=\count185
\c@subsubsection=\count186
\c@paragraph=\count187
\c@subparagraph=\count188
\c@figure=\count189
\c@table=\count190
\abovecaptionskip=\skip47
\belowcaptionskip=\skip48
\bibindent=\dimen138
) (/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/inputenc.sty
Package: inputenc 2021/02/14 v1.3d Input encoding file
\inpenc@prehook=\toks16
\inpenc@posthook=\toks17
) (/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/geometry/geometry.sty
Package: geometry 2020/01/02 v5.9 Page Geometry
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty
Package: keyval 2014/10/28 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
\KV@toks@=\toks18
) (/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/iftex/ifvtex.sty
Package: ifvtex 2019/10/25 v1.7 ifvtex legacy package. Use iftex instead.
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/iftex/iftex.sty
Package: iftex 2020/03/06 v1.0d TeX engine tests
))
\Gm@cnth=\count191
\Gm@cntv=\count192
\c@Gm@tempcnt=\count193
\Gm@bindingoffset=\dimen139
\Gm@wd@mp=\dimen140
\Gm@odd@mp=\dimen141
\Gm@even@mp=\dimen142
\Gm@layoutwidth=\dimen143
\Gm@layoutheight=\dimen144
\Gm@layouthoffset=\dimen145
\Gm@layoutvoffset=\dimen146
\Gm@dimlist=\toks19
) (/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/subfiles/subfiles.sty
Package: subfiles 2020/11/14 v2.2 Multi-file projects (package)
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/import/import.sty
Package: import 2020/04/01  v 6.2
)) (/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fancyhdr/fancyhdr.sty
Package: fancyhdr 2021/01/28 v4.0.1 Extensive control of page headers and foote
rs
\f@nch@headwidth=\skip49
\f@nch@O@elh=\skip50
\f@nch@O@erh=\skip51
\f@nch@O@olh=\skip52
\f@nch@O@orh=\skip53
\f@nch@O@elf=\skip54
\f@nch@O@erf=\skip55
\f@nch@O@olf=\skip56
\f@nch@O@orf=\skip57
) (/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsmath.sty
Package: amsmath 2021/04/20 v2.17j AMS math features
\@mathmargin=\skip58
For additional information on amsmath, use the `?' option.
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amstext.sty
Package: amstext 2000/06/29 v2.01 AMS text
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsgen.sty
File: amsgen.sty 1999/11/30 v2.0 generic functions
\@emptytoks=\toks20
\ex@=\dimen147
)) (/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsbsy.sty
Package: amsbsy 1999/11/29 v1.2d Bold Symbols
\pmbraise@=\dimen148
) (/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsopn.sty
Package: amsopn 2016/03/08 v2.02 operator names
)
\inf@bad=\count194
LaTeX Info: Redefining \frac on input line 234.
\uproot@=\count195
\leftroot@=\count196
LaTeX Info: Redefining \overline on input line 399.
\classnum@=\count197
\DOTSCASE@=\count198
LaTeX Info: Redefining \ldots on input line 496.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \dots on input line 499.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \cdots on input line 620.
\Mathstrutbox@=\box50
\strutbox@=\box51
\big@size=\dimen149
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring font encoding OML on input line 743.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring font encoding OMS on input line 744.
\macc@depth=\count199
\c@MaxMatrixCols=\count266
\dotsspace@=\muskip16
\c@parentequation=\count267
\dspbrk@lvl=\count268
\tag@help=\toks21
\row@=\count269
\column@=\count270
\maxfields@=\count271
\andhelp@=\toks22
\eqnshift@=\dimen150
\alignsep@=\dimen151
\tagshift@=\dimen152
\tagwidth@=\dimen153
\totwidth@=\dimen154
\lineht@=\dimen155
\@envbody=\toks23
\multlinegap=\skip59
\multlinetaggap=\skip60
\mathdisplay@stack=\toks24
LaTeX Info: Redefining \[ on input line 2923.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \] on input line 2924.
) (/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/amssymb.sty
Package: amssymb 2013/01/14 v3.01 AMS font symbols
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/amsfonts.sty
Package: amsfonts 2013/01/14 v3.01 Basic AMSFonts support
\symAMSa=\mathgroup4
\symAMSb=\mathgroup5
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \hbar on input line 98.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathfrak' in version `bold'
(Font)                  U/euf/m/n --> U/euf/b/n on input line 106.
)) (/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/biblatex.sty
Package: biblatex 2022/06/22 v3.18 programmable bibliographies (PK/MW)
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pdftexcmds/pdftexcmds.sty
Package: pdftexcmds 2020-06-27 v0.33 Utility functions of pdfTeX for LuaTeX (HO
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/infwarerr/infwarerr.sty
Package: infwarerr 2019/12/03 v1.5 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
) (/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/ltxcmds/ltxcmds.sty
Package: ltxcmds 2020-05-10 v1.25 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
)
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdf@primitive is available.
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdf@ifprimitive is available.
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdfdraftmode found.
) (/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/etoolbox/etoolbox.sty
Package: etoolbox 2020/10/05 v2.5k e-TeX tools for LaTeX (JAW)
\etb@tempcnta=\count272
) (/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/kvoptions/kvoptions.sty
Package: kvoptions 2020-10-07 v3.14 Key value format for package options (HO)
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/kvsetkeys/kvsetkeys.sty
Package: kvsetkeys 2019/12/15 v1.18 Key value parser (HO)
)) (/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/logreq/logreq.sty
Package: logreq 2010/08/04 v1.0 xml request logger
\lrq@indent=\count273
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/logreq/logreq.def
File: logreq.def 2010/08/04 v1.0 logreq spec v1.0
)) (/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ifthen.sty
Package: ifthen 2020/11/24 v1.1c Standard LaTeX ifthen package (DPC)
) (/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/url/url.sty
\Urlmuskip=\muskip17
Package: url 2013/09/16  ver 3.4  Verb mode for urls, etc.
)
\c@tabx@nest=\count274
\c@listtotal=\count275
\c@listcount=\count276
\c@liststart=\count277
\c@liststop=\count278
\c@citecount=\count279
\c@citetotal=\count280
\c@multicitecount=\count281
\c@multicitetotal=\count282
...
\c@mincompwidth=\count319
Package biblatex Info: Trying to load biblatex default data model...
Package biblatex Info: ... file 'blx-dm.def' found.
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/blx-dm.def
File: blx-dm.def 2022/06/22 v3.18 biblatex localization (PK/MW)
)
Package biblatex Info: Trying to load biblatex style data model...
Package biblatex Info: ... file 'ieee.dbx' not found.
Package biblatex Info: Trying to load biblatex custom data model...
Package biblatex Info: ... file 'biblatex-dm.cfg' not found.
\c@afterword=\count320
\c@savedafterword=\count321
\c@annotator=\count322
\c@savedannotator=\count323
\c@author=\count324
\c@savedauthor=\count325
\c@bookauthor=\count326
\c@savedbookauthor=\count327
\c@commentator=\count328
\c@savedcommentator=\count329
\c@editor=\count330
\c@savededitor=\count331
\c@editora=\count332
\c@savededitora=\count333
\c@editorb=\count334
\c@savededitorb=\count335
\c@editorc=\count336
\c@savededitorc=\count337
\c@foreword=\count338
\c@savedforeword=\count339
\c@holder=\count340
\c@savedholder=\count341
\c@introduction=\count342
\c@savedintroduction=\count343
\c@namea=\count344
\c@savednamea=\count345
\c@nameb=\count346
\c@savednameb=\count347
\c@namec=\count348
\c@savednamec=\count349
\c@translator=\count350
\c@savedtranslator=\count351
\c@shortauthor=\count352
\c@savedshortauthor=\count353
\c@shorteditor=\count354
\c@savedshorteditor=\count355
\c@labelname=\count356
\c@savedlabelname=\count357
\c@institution=\count358
\c@savedinstitution=\count359
\c@lista=\count360
\c@savedlista=\count361
\c@listb=\count362
\c@savedlistb=\count363
\c@listc=\count364
\c@savedlistc=\count365
\c@listd=\count366
\c@savedlistd=\count367
\c@liste=\count368
\c@savedliste=\count369
\c@listf=\count370
\c@savedlistf=\count371
\c@location=\count372
\c@savedlocation=\count373
\c@organization=\count374
\c@savedorganization=\count375
\c@origlocation=\count376
\c@savedoriglocation=\count377
\c@origpublisher=\count378
\c@savedorigpublisher=\count379
\c@publisher=\count380
\c@savedpublisher=\count381
\c@language=\count382
\c@savedlanguage=\count383
\c@origlanguage=\count384
\c@savedoriglanguage=\count385
\c@pageref=\count386
\c@savedpageref=\count387
\shorthandwidth=\skip69
\shortjournalwidth=\skip70
\shortserieswidth=\skip71
\shorttitlewidth=\skip72
\shortauthorwidth=\skip73
\shorteditorwidth=\skip74
\locallabelnumberwidth=\skip75
\locallabelalphawidth=\skip76
\localshorthandwidth=\skip77
\localshortjournalwidth=\skip78
\localshortserieswidth=\skip79
\localshorttitlewidth=\skip80
\localshortauthorwidth=\skip81
\localshorteditorwidth=\skip82
Package biblatex Info: Trying to load compatibility code...
Package biblatex Info: ... file 'blx-compat.def' found.
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/blx-compat.def
File: blx-compat.def 2022/06/22 v3.18 biblatex compatibility (PK/MW)
)
Package biblatex Info: Trying to load generic definitions...
Package biblatex Info: ... file 'biblatex.def' found.
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/biblatex.def
File: biblatex.def 2022/06/22 v3.18 biblatex compatibility (PK/MW)
\c@textcitecount=\count388
\c@textcitetotal=\count389
\c@textcitemaxnames=\count390
\c@biburlbigbreakpenalty=\count391
\c@biburlbreakpenalty=\count392
\c@biburlnumpenalty=\count393
\c@biburlucpenalty=\count394
\c@biburllcpenalty=\count395
\biburlbigskip=\muskip18
\biburlnumskip=\muskip19
\biburlucskip=\muskip20
\biburllcskip=\muskip21
\c@smartand=\count396
)
Package biblatex Info: Trying to load bibliography style 'ieee'...
Package biblatex Info: ... file 'ieee.bbx' found.
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex-ieee/ieee.bbx
File: ieee.bbx 2021/12/06 v1.3f biblatex bibliography style
Package biblatex Info: Trying to load bibliography style 'numeric-comp'...
Package biblatex Info: ... file 'numeric-comp.bbx' found.
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/bbx/numeric-comp.bbx
File: numeric-comp.bbx 2022/06/22 v3.18 biblatex bibliography style (PK/MW)
Package biblatex Info: Trying to load bibliography style 'numeric'...
Package biblatex Info: ... file 'numeric.bbx' found.
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/bbx/numeric.bbx
File: numeric.bbx 2022/06/22 v3.18 biblatex bibliography style (PK/MW)
Package biblatex Info: Trying to load bibliography style 'standard'...
Package biblatex Info: ... file 'standard.bbx' found.
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/bbx/standard.bbx
File: standard.bbx 2022/06/22 v3.18 biblatex bibliography style (PK/MW)
\c@bbx:relatedcount=\count397
\c@bbx:relatedtotal=\count398
))))
Package biblatex Info: Trying to load citation style 'ieee'...
Package biblatex Info: ... file 'ieee.cbx' found.
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex-ieee/ieee.cbx
File: ieee.cbx 2021/12/06 v1.3f biblatex citation style
Package biblatex Info: Trying to load citation style 'numeric-comp'...
Package biblatex Info: ... file 'numeric-comp.cbx' found.
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/cbx/numeric-comp.cbx
File: numeric-comp.cbx 2022/06/22 v3.18 biblatex citation style (PK/MW)
\c@cbx@tempcnta=\count399
\c@cbx@tempcntb=\count400
\c@cbx@tempcntc=\count401
\c@cbx@tempcntd=\count402
Package biblatex Info: Redefining '\cite'.
Package biblatex Info: Redefining '\parencite'.
Package biblatex Info: Redefining '\footcite'.
Package biblatex Info: Redefining '\footcitetext'.
Package biblatex Info: Redefining '\smartcite'.
Package biblatex Info: Redefining '\supercite'.
Package biblatex Info: Redefining '\textcite'.
Package biblatex Info: Redefining '\textcites'.
Package biblatex Info: Redefining '\cites'.
Package biblatex Info: Redefining '\parencites'.
Package biblatex Info: Redefining '\smartcites'.
)
Package biblatex Info: Redefining '\cite'.
Package biblatex Info: Redefining '\supercite'.
Package biblatex Info: Redefining '\cites'.
)
Package biblatex Info: Trying to load configuration file...
Package biblatex Info: ... file 'biblatex.cfg' found.
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/biblatex.cfg
File: biblatex.cfg 
)
Package biblatex Info: Input encoding 'utf8' detected.
Package biblatex Info: Document encoding is UTF8 ....
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/expl3.sty
Package: expl3 2021-06-18 L3 programming layer (loader) 
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-pdftex.def
File: l3backend-pdftex.def 2021-05-07 L3 backend support: PDF output (pdfTeX)
\l__color_backend_stack_int=\count403
\l__pdf_internal_box=\box52
))
Package biblatex Info: ... and expl3
(biblatex)             2021-06-18 L3 programming layer (loader) 
(biblatex)             is new enough (at least 2020/04/06),
(biblatex)             setting 'casechanger=expl3'.
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/blx-case-expl3.sty (/usr
/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3packages/xparse/xparse.sty
Package: xparse 2021-06-18 L3 Experimental document command parser
)
Package: blx-case-expl3 2022/06/22 v3.18 expl3 case changing code for biblatex
)) (/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/hyperref.sty
Package: hyperref 2021-06-07 v7.00m Hypertext links for LaTeX
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/kvdefinekeys/kvdefinekeys.sty
Package: kvdefinekeys 2019-12-19 v1.6 Define keys (HO)
) (/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pdfescape/pdfescape.sty
Package: pdfescape 2019/12/09 v1.15 Implements pdfTeX's escape features (HO)
) (/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hycolor/hycolor.sty
Package: hycolor 2020-01-27 v1.10 Color options for hyperref/bookmark (HO)
) (/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/letltxmacro/letltxmacro.sty
Package: letltxmacro 2019/12/03 v1.6 Let assignment for LaTeX macros (HO)
) (/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/auxhook/auxhook.sty
Package: auxhook 2019-12-17 v1.6 Hooks for auxiliary files (HO)
)
\@linkdim=\dimen156
\Hy@linkcounter=\count404
\Hy@pagecounter=\count405
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/pd1enc.def
File: pd1enc.def 2021-06-07 v7.00m Hyperref: PDFDocEncoding definition (HO)
Now handling font encoding PD1 ...
... no UTF-8 mapping file for font encoding PD1
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/hyperref-langpatches.def
File: hyperref-langpatches.def 2021-06-07 v7.00m Hyperref: patches for babel la
nguages
) (/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/intcalc/intcalc.sty
Package: intcalc 2019/12/15 v1.3 Expandable calculations with integers (HO)
) (/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/etexcmds/etexcmds.sty
Package: etexcmds 2019/12/15 v1.7 Avoid name clashes with e-TeX commands (HO)
)
\Hy@SavedSpaceFactor=\count406
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/puenc.def
File: puenc.def 2021-06-07 v7.00m Hyperref: PDF Unicode definition (HO)
Now handling font encoding PU ...
... no UTF-8 mapping file for font encoding PU
)
Package hyperref Info: Option `breaklinks' set `true' on input line 4073.
Package hyperref Info: Hyper figures OFF on input line 4192.
Package hyperref Info: Link nesting OFF on input line 4197.
Package hyperref Info: Hyper index ON on input line 4200.
Package hyperref Info: Plain pages OFF on input line 4207.
Package hyperref Info: Backreferencing OFF on input line 4212.
Package hyperref Info: Implicit mode ON; LaTeX internals redefined.
Package hyperref Info: Bookmarks ON on input line 4445.
\c@Hy@tempcnt=\count407
LaTeX Info: Redefining \url on input line 4804.
\XeTeXLinkMargin=\dimen157
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/bitset/bitset.sty
Package: bitset 2019/12/09 v1.3 Handle bit-vector datatype (HO)
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/bigintcalc/bigintcalc.sty
Package: bigintcalc 2019/12/15 v1.5 Expandable calculations on big integers (HO
)
))
\Fld@menulength=\count408
\Field@Width=\dimen158
\Fld@charsize=\dimen159
Package hyperref Info: Hyper figures OFF on input line 6076.
Package hyperref Info: Link nesting OFF on input line 6081.
Package hyperref Info: Hyper index ON on input line 6084.
Package hyperref Info: backreferencing OFF on input line 6091.
Package hyperref Info: Link coloring OFF on input line 6096.
Package hyperref Info: Link coloring with OCG OFF on input line 6101.
Package hyperref Info: PDF/A mode OFF on input line 6106.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \ref on input line 6146.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \pageref on input line 6150.
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/atbegshi-ltx.sty
Package: atbegshi-ltx 2021/01/10 v1.0c Emulation of the original atbegshi
package with kernel methods
)
\Hy@abspage=\count409
\c@Item=\count410
\c@Hfootnote=\count411
)
Package hyperref Info: Driver (autodetected): hpdftex.
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/hpdftex.def
File: hpdftex.def 2021-06-07 v7.00m Hyperref driver for pdfTeX
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/atveryend-ltx.sty
Package: atveryend-ltx 2020/08/19 v1.0a Emulation of the original atvery packag
e
with kernel methods
)
\Fld@listcount=\count412
\c@bookmark@seq@number=\count413

(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/rerunfilecheck/rerunfilecheck.sty
Package: rerunfilecheck 2019/12/05 v1.9 Rerun checks for auxiliary files (HO)

(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/uniquecounter/uniquecounter.sty
Package: uniquecounter 2019/12/15 v1.4 Provide unlimited unique counter (HO)
)
Package uniquecounter Info: New unique counter `rerunfilecheck' on input line 2
86.
)
\Hy@SectionHShift=\skip83
) (/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/footmisc/footmisc.sty
Package: footmisc 2022/03/08 v6.0d a miscellany of footnote facilities
\FN@temptoken=\toks25
\footnotemargin=\dimen160
\@outputbox@depth=\dimen161
Package footmisc Info: Declaring symbol style bringhurst on input line 695.
Package footmisc Info: Declaring symbol style chicago on input line 703.
Package footmisc Info: Declaring symbol style wiley on input line 712.
Package footmisc Info: Declaring symbol style lamport-robust on input line 723.

Package footmisc Info: Declaring symbol style lamport* on input line 743.
Package footmisc Info: Declaring symbol style lamport*-robust on input line 764
.
) (./myMacros.sty
Package: myMacros Macros for my document
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/xspace.sty
Package: xspace 2014/10/28 v1.13 Space after command names (DPC,MH)
) (/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xcolor/xcolor.sty
Package: xcolor 2022/06/12 v2.14 LaTeX color extensions (UK)
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/color.cfg
File: color.cfg 2016/01/02 v1.6 sample color configuration
)
Package xcolor Info: Driver file: pdftex.def on input line 227.
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-def/pdftex.def
File: pdftex.def 2020/10/05 v1.2a Graphics/color driver for pdftex
)
Package xcolor Info: Model `cmy' substituted by `cmy0' on input line 1353.
Package xcolor Info: Model `hsb' substituted by `rgb' on input line 1357.
Package xcolor Info: Model `RGB' extended on input line 1369.
Package xcolor Info: Model `HTML' substituted by `rgb' on input line 1371.
Package xcolor Info: Model `Hsb' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1372.
Package xcolor Info: Model `tHsb' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1373.
Package xcolor Info: Model `HSB' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1374.
Package xcolor Info: Model `Gray' substituted by `gray' on input line 1375.
Package xcolor Info: Model `wave' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1376.
) (/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontawesome/fontawesome.sty
Package: fontawesome 2016/05/15 v4.6.3.1 font awesome icons
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/iftex/ifxetex.sty
Package: ifxetex 2019/10/25 v0.7 ifxetex legacy package. Use iftex instead.
) (/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/iftex/ifluatex.sty
Package: ifluatex 2019/10/25 v1.5 ifluatex legacy package. Use iftex instead.
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontawesome/fontawesomesymbols-ge
neric.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontawesome/fontawesomesymbols-pd
ftex.tex)))
\@quotelevel=\count414
\@quotereset=\count415
(./output.aux)
\openout1 = `output.aux'.

LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 24.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 24.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 24.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 24.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 24.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 24.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 24.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 24.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for TS1/cmr/m/n on input line 24.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 24.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 24.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 24.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 24.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 24.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for PD1/pdf/m/n on input line 24.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 24.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for PU/pdf/m/n on input line 24.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 24.
*geometry* driver: auto-detecting
*geometry* detected driver: pdftex
*geometry* verbose mode - [ preamble ] result:
* driver: pdftex
* paper: <default>
* layout: <same size as paper>
* layoutoffset:(h,v)=(0.0pt,0.0pt)
* modes: 
* h-part:(L,W,R)=(72.26999pt, 469.75502pt, 72.26999pt)
* v-part:(T,H,B)=(72.26999pt, 650.43001pt, 72.26999pt)
* \paperwidth=614.295pt
* \paperheight=794.96999pt
* \textwidth=469.75502pt
* \textheight=650.43001pt
* \oddsidemargin=0.0pt
* \evensidemargin=0.0pt
* \topmargin=-37.0pt
* \headheight=12.0pt
* \headsep=25.0pt
* \topskip=10.0pt
* \footskip=30.0pt
* \marginparwidth=65.0pt
* \marginparsep=11.0pt
* \columnsep=10.0pt
* \skip\footins=9.0pt plus 4.0pt minus 2.0pt
* \hoffset=0.0pt
* \voffset=0.0pt
* \mag=1000
* \@twocolumnfalse
* \@twosidefalse
* \@mparswitchfalse
* \@reversemarginfalse
* (1in=72.27pt=25.4mm, 1cm=28.453pt)

Package biblatex Info: Trying to load language 'english'...
Package biblatex Info: ... file 'english.lbx' found.
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/lbx/english.lbx
File: english.lbx 2022/06/22 v3.18 biblatex localization (PK/MW)
)
Package biblatex Info: Input encoding 'utf8' detected.
Package biblatex Info: Automatic encoding selection.
(biblatex)             Assuming data encoding 'utf8'.
\openout3 = `output.bcf'.

Package biblatex Info: Trying to load bibliographic data...
Package biblatex Info: ... file 'output.bbl' not found.
No file output.bbl.
Package biblatex Info: Reference section=0 on input line 24.
Package biblatex Info: Reference segment=0 on input line 24.
Package hyperref Info: Link coloring OFF on input line 24.
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/nameref.sty
Package: nameref 2021-04-02 v2.47 Cross-referencing by name of section
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/refcount/refcount.sty
Package: refcount 2019/12/15 v3.6 Data extraction from label references (HO)
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/gettitlestring/gettitlestring.s
ty
Package: gettitlestring 2019/12/15 v1.6 Cleanup title references (HO)
)
\c@section@level=\count416
)
LaTeX Info: Redefining \ref on input line 24.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \pageref on input line 24.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \nameref on input line 24.
(./output.out) (./output.out)
\@outlinefile=\write4
\openout4 = `output.out'.

(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/context/base/mkii/supp-pdf.mkii
[Loading MPS to PDF converter (version 2006.09.02).]
\scratchcounter=\count417
\scratchdimen=\dimen162
\scratchbox=\box53
\nofMPsegments=\count418
\nofMParguments=\count419
\everyMPshowfont=\toks26
\MPscratchCnt=\count420
\MPscratchDim=\dimen163
\MPnumerator=\count421
\makeMPintoPDFobject=\count422
\everyMPtoPDFconversion=\toks27
)
LaTeX Font Info:    Trying to load font information for U+msa on input line 35.

(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/umsa.fd
File: umsa.fd 2013/01/14 v3.01 AMS symbols A
)
LaTeX Font Info:    Trying to load font information for U+msb on input line 35.

(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/umsb.fd
File: umsb.fd 2013/01/14 v3.01 AMS symbols B
) [1

{/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}] [2

]
Package biblatex Info: Reference segment=1 on input line 52.
Package biblatex Info: Setting label 'refsegment:01' on input line 52.
(./output.toc)
\tf@toc=\write5
\openout5 = `output.toc'.

(./chapters/imports.tex (./chapters/Introduction/imports.texpdfTeX warning (ext
4): destination with the same identifier (name{page.1}) has been already used, 
duplicate ignored
<to be read again> 
                   \relax 
l.1 \chapter
            {Introduction} [1


]
Chapter 1.
Package biblatex Info: Reference segment=2 on input line 1.
Package biblatex Info: Setting label 'refsegment:02' on input line 1.
(./chapters/Introduction/content/test1.tex) (./chapters/Introduction/conten
t/test2.texpdfTeX warning (ext4): destination with the same identifier (n
ame{page.2}) has been already used, duplicate ignored
<to be read again> 
                   \relax 
l.12         \item `
                    `Lorem ipsum" dolor sit amet...
[2

]

LaTeX Warning: Citation 'abcd' on page 3 undefined on input line 16.

)) (./chapters/test1/foobar.tex
Overfull \hbox (4.29929pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 21--1
\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur
 []

[3]
Chapter 2.
Package biblatex Info: Reference segment=3 on input line 1.
Package biblatex Info: Setting label 'refsegment:03' on input line 1.
(./chapters/test2/content/summary.tex)) (./chapters/abcd/imports.tex [4

]
Chapter 3.
Package biblatex Info: Reference segment=4 on input line 1.
Package biblatex Info: Setting label 'refsegment:04' on input line 1.
) (./chapters/test3/imports.tex [5

]
Chapter 4.
Package biblatex Info: Reference segment=5 on input line 1.
Package biblatex Info: Setting label 'refsegment:05' on input line 1.
) (./chapters/test4/imports.tex [6

]
Chapter 5.
Package biblatex Info: Reference segment=6 on input line 1.
Package biblatex Info: Setting label 'refsegment:06' on input line 1.
))

LaTeX Warning: Empty bibliography on input line 59.

[7

] (./output.aux)

LaTeX Warning: There were undefined references.

Package rerunfilecheck Info: File `output.out' has not changed.
(rerunfilecheck)             Checksum: 5DCE4B4439B3D0E77949FFD08DE4D6CB;1275.

Package biblatex Warning: Please (re)run Biber on the file:
(biblatex)                output
(biblatex)                and rerun LaTeX afterwards.

Package logreq Info: Writing requests to 'output.run.xml'.
\openout1 = `output.run.xml'.

...
```

I truncated (likely irrelevant) parts of the logs to meet StackExchange's character limit.

Comment: You posted the pdflatex log. It's not pdflatex that needs to read the .bib file: all pdflatex does is write the name of that file (and the citation keys) to the .bcf file, so that when biber processes it, it knows where to look. It's biber that needs to read the .bib file to create a .bbl file. Biber should be generating its own log (ending in `.blg`): what does it say?

Comment: Try a simple example document like https://gist.github.com/moewew/e92edad4f3b96d3ed9ef0308d61a6945 first: No frills like `subfiles`. That document can be run on any system with `biblatex` and Biber installed. The `.bib` file that is used will be present on such a system and found automatically. Normally Overleaf uses `latexmk` to run pdfLaTeX and Biber automatically, so you should get both a `.log` and `.blg` file: Check both of them for errors and warnings.

Comment: I don't have a `.blg` file, but here is my [output.bcf file](https://pastebin.com/0EjA4xDs). Overleaf gives me the option to download the following files: aux file, bcf file, log file, out file, pdf file, run.xml file, stdout file, synctex.gz file, and toc file.

Comment: The `.bcf` does not help here. If you have no `.blg`, then the most likely explanation is that Biber was not run at all. On Overleaf's own system, they always run `latexmk` which will run Biber (at least for the example I posted above). But maybe you have to configure something to that effect on your own instance or something else is wrong. But I'm guessing this is something to ask Overleaf support.

Comment: I will reach out to them to check. Thank you for your help—I will post when I have an update!

Comment: I have opened an issue in the [Overleaf GitHub repository](https://github.com/overleaf/overleaf/). Please see [overleaf/overleaf#1030](https://github.com/overleaf/overleaf/issues/1030).